# set types to useFetch using generics with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

I have a useFetch, to whom I want to send an argument URL of type string, forgot to mention it is to consume an API. The problem I have is that it does not recognize the result. I am using generic types in useFetch. If I use the types created in my interface everything is clean and there are no errors.

But my idea is that useFetch should be agnostic. The error I get from the linter is Property results does not exist on type <useFetchState<movieApi | null>>. In the useFetch file, I have another error. The argument of type null is not assignable to parameter  <useFetchState<movieApi | null>>.

useFetch code.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

type useFetchState<T> = {
    data: null | T;
}

export const useFetch = <T>( url: string )  => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<useFetchState<T | null>>(null)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null)

    const getData = (url:string) => {
        setLoading(true)
        return fetch(url)
            .then((res) => {
                const showError = {
                    err:true,
                    statuscode:res.status,
                    message:"Error in your request"
                }
                if(!res.ok){
                    throw showError;
                }
                return res.json()
            })
            .then((data) => {
                setData(data)
            })
            .catch((err) => setError(err))
            .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false);
            })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData(url)
    }, [url])
    
    return {data, loading, error}
}
```

Home component code.

```
import { movieApi, movieApiResult } from "../../hooks/useFetch/interface";
import { useFetch } from "../../hooks/useFetch/useFetch";
import "./home.css";

const Home = () => {
  const IMGPATH = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280";

  const { data } = useFetch<movieApi>(
    "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=04c35731a5ee918f014970082a0088b1&page=2"
  );

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {data?.results.map((item: movieApiResult) => (
        <div
          key={item.id}
          className="item"
          //onClick={() => handleClick(item.id)}
        >
          <img
            src={`${IMGPATH}${item.poster_path}`}
            alt={item.title}
            className="image"
          />
          <p>{item.title}</p>
          <span>{item.vote_average}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

interfaces

```
export interface movieApi {
  page: number;
  results: movieApiResult[];
  total_pages: number;
  total_results: number;
}

export interface movieApiResult {
  adult: boolean;
  backdrop_path: string;
  genre_ids: number[];
  id: number;
  original_language: string;
  original_title: string;
  overview: string;
  popularity: number;
  poster_path: string;
  release_date: string;
  title: string;
  video: boolean;
  vote_average: number;
  vote_count: number;
}
```

ok,removing the useFetchState works, the problem is fixed, but if I create a useContext, and send that data to the Home component, the error appears again in the "results".

```
type props = {
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
};
interface MoviesTypes {
  data: movieApi | movieObject | null;
  loading: boolean;
  setUrl: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
  handleClick: (id: number) => void;
  IMGPATH: string;
}
const MoviesContext = createContext<MoviesTypes>({} as MoviesTypes);

export const MoviesProvider = ({ children }: props) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState<string>(
    "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=04c35731a5ee918f014970082a0088b1&page=2"
  );
  const [ids, setIds] = useState<null | number>(null);
  const { data, loading } = useFetch<movieApi | movieObject>(url);

  const IMGPATH = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280";
  const handleClick = (id: number) => {
    setUrl(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=04c35731a5ee918f014970082a0088b1`
    );
    setIds(id);
  };

  return (
    <MoviesContext.Provider
      value={{
        data,
        loading,
        setUrl,
        handleClick,
        IMGPATH,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </MoviesContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useMovies = () => {
  const context = useContext(MoviesContext);

  return context;
};
```

I guess it must be a fairly easy problem. But I'm just getting started with typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `useFetchState` is slightly off - its type is

```
{
    data: null | T;
}
```

but then you pass in a value that must match it (through `useState`) into it not *an object with a possibly null `data`*, but `null` itself.

```
useState<useFetchState<T | null>>(null)
```

The `useFetchState` isn't doing much for you anyway. I'd change the `useState` type to be just null or T, no need for anything else.

```
const [data, setData] = useState<T | null>(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you do not need this:

```
type useFetchState<T> = {
    data: null | T;
}
```

Just change your `useFetch` like below (don't forget the `<T,>` if you are in .tsx) :

```
export const useFetch = <T,>(url: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  ...
}
```

and everything will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to change this restriction here (since you said it should be agnostic) **from:**

```
const [data, setData] = useState<useFetchState<T | null>>(null);
```

**To:**

```
const [data, setData] = useState<any | null>(null); // even only any will do the job
```

Because you may get the response as array of objects, or even as object contains data, status, etc ...
So you never know the exact type of the response data.

Comment: I want it to be sometimes an array, and sometimes an object. Because I have a URL that returns an object with many properties, on the other hand I have an object with other properties like results, which is an array. 
I'm thinking maybe it's not the best to have a useFetch if I want to have strict typing because each API returns different things.
What do you think?

Comment: i have a similar custom hook called useForm, there i have no clue which initial state structure i'll receive so the type of state is always `any`, because i cannot send types to it, i would like as i said to keep it as much as possible generic